# Smartest way to parse a lot of commands?

Tags: java

for an assignment I need to create a rudimentary processor that can work with easy functions, such as ADD, SUB, LOAD, STORE and JUMP

As input I have to use a text file, parse the 20 different commands and then execute them.

My question is how to best parse the strings, match them with the corresponding commands and then execute them?

For example, I could parse the file line by line, tokenize the string, send the tokens through a massive if-else statement containing all the commands, then call the commands by creating a class for each command (beforehand) and then execute that class.

But I don't think that this would be the best way to go about it. Is there any better way or could I improve something in my example?

Comment: is the structure of the file defined or you can use your own format (like JSON)?

Comment: It is defined as: |Index|*whitespace*|Command|*whitespace*|(optional) Value|. I am currently just cutting the string at the whitespaces into tokens and save them in a string array.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you expect us to do your work for you?

Comment: I am not. I wrote an example of how I would do it in the OP. But especially the giant if-else statement irks me. As if worte in the OP, I'd like to ask if there is any better way to do it. You don't have to code it for me.

Comment: What about what you said, but instead of having an `if/else if/else` code you do a do a map in which you have the keys as the command name and as value a `Function` taking all the arguments of the command, and you just `get` the handler of the command from the Map?

Comment: That can be done in many different ways. Mostly depends on what this exercise is supposed to demonstrate. The simplest way is, as you mentioned, a massive if-else statement. You can replace it with a `Map` as already suggested. Alternatively, you can use `switch-case` statement on string value (this translates into a sort of hard-coded dispatch similar to hashmap with less overhead). And if you want something really challenging you can write an ANTLR grammar, build parser out of it, and have fun.

Comment: The topics to research: parsing, tokenizing, abstract syntax tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the command as an interface and map it to `String`.

```
interface Command{
    void execute();
}

Map<String, Command> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Next map all the implementations of your commands accordingly:

```
map.put("ADD", () -> System.out.println("Calling Add"));
```

Then once you are tokenizing the lines just search the map and execute the commands, and don't forget to check if the command exists.

```
for (String token : tokens){
      map.getOrDefault(token, () -> System.out.println("Command " + token + " not found")).execute();
}
```

Comment: Pretty much what I'd do and have done on systems handling thousands of requests per minute that needed to potentially support more operations in the future.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider yep, this is the purest form of a builder pattern. Once you command become more complex, you might switch hashmap with a different data structure that will better sweet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format that you stated in your follow-up comment, I would use the `Scanner` class to read each line delimited by whitespace as that is the separator in your text input.

From there, you can use a switch statement to decide which operation to do based on the string you extract from the text input. Since you have to write the logic for each command anyways, a switch statement will look a lot cleaner than a gigantic if-else nightmare

EDIT:

I will also clarify how to do this further:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("ints.txt"));
while (reader.hasNext()){
    Scanner parser = new Scanner(reader.nextLine());
    parser.useDelimiter(" ");
    //access each piece of the command by using parser.next();
}
```